# IPhone - 2d Animation - Translations of multiple objects

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation

I would love if someone could give me a short breakdown on what's the best way in terms of memory usage for animating UIImageViews (translation, without sprites).

More specifically, I need to animate multiple objects on screen at the same time (let's say up to 15-20);
Also, I have to be able to interrupt the animation due to collision between some of these objects.

The kind of animation I need is a simple translation. If it's possible, I would concat this translation with rotations and scalings (secondary).

I'd prefer not to use OpenGL because I think that this kind ow work doesn't require it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I know you'd rather not use OpenGL or sprites, but I'd suggest you take a look at [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  It makes it fairly easy to do what you want (rotation, translation, scale, collision detection, etc.).  I'd barely know how to begin to try to do the same thing using just the Core Animation API.

Answer (score 0):

CoreAnimation can do this handily. The code below will animate the translation of a view. It's also possible to stop the animation half-way and get its current state for feeding into your collision detection algorithm, but you'll have to read up a bit on Core Animation for that.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
view.center = CGPointMake (view.center.x + 50, view.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I am already using core animations, but was wondering if there was some better way to handle this situation. Seems like the program is very cpu-intensive as it is; I still haven't tested on a device by the way.

Comment: If you want quality and ease of use like CA but not using OpenGL, well... I wish you luck! It's not easy to replicate what the graphics guys at Apple did.

Comment: This may be true, but I wish I wouldn't face CA limits so early. We are talking about the most basic of the animations, just involving more objects. Maybe I didn't grasp how CA are thought.

Comment: See what happens on the device…